# Android requestLocationUpdates with a 15 minute interval is causing gps indicator to fire constantly

Tags: android, gps

this is the requestLocationUpdates call I am using, 900000 (15 minutes) and 500 meters shouldn't be causing the gps to fire constantly, its really draining battery...

I know this code isn't helpful.. But does anyone know why this might be happening?

in my onStartCommand

```
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 900000, 500, locationListener);
mLocation = mlocManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

and then

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLocation = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {}
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The time parameter to `requestLocationUpdates()` is a hint, not a rule -- you may get locations more frequently than this.

If you want to stop consuming battery due to having the GPS on, call `removeUpdates()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I just thought it was weird because the gps icon does not ever go away after my service starts.

Comment: @David: If you are testing on the emulator, the GPS icon never goes away. It's a long-standing flaw in the emulator. On a device, the GPS icon should go away when you call `removeUpdates()`, assuming no other app is keeping GPS powered on.